# Smart contract - dividend cash payment

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, nft

I am wondering if it is possible to setup a smart contract which returns cash (and not a token) directly to the wallet of the NFT's owner every time a company decides to do a dividend payment (for example).

If so, how is it possible? Do I need to specify this cash distribution while setting up the smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return fiat money from EVM smart contracts, however you can transfer native token, like ETH on ethereum. Consider following function:

```
function withraw(address payabale _to, uint256 _amount) public {
    require(_to.balance >= _amount, "Not enough funds");
    _to.transfer(_amount);
}
```

This will transfer ETH to `_to` address and then this address can exchange it to fiat money. The logic when, how and who should call `withdraw` method should, and can, be implemented in contract. That gives transparency for all contract users.